# YII2 - Partial update on anchor tag click

Tags: javascript, onclick, yii2, partials

I'm having some trouble to render partial when clicking on a anchor tag in Yii2.

My view code is as follows :

```
<div class="col-md-5 module">

    <h2><?php echo $client->subtitle ?></h2>

    <div class="text-center industries-wrapper">

        <div class="center-wrapper clearfix">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                <?php foreach ($clientMarkets as $key => $clientMarket) : ?>
                    <li <?= ($key == 0) ? 'class="active"' : '' ?>>
                        <a <?= ($key == 0) ? 'href="#1a"' : 'href="#2a"' ?> data-toggle="tab">
                            <?php echo $clientMarket->title ?>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="tab-content center-wrapper clearfix">
            <?php foreach ($clientMarkets as $key => $clientMarket) : ?>
                <div id="1a" <?= ($key == 0) ? 'id="1a"' : 'id="2a"' ?>
                     class="tab-pane<?= ($key == 0) ? ' active' : '' ?>">

                    <div class="contact-info">
                        <ul>
                            <?php foreach ($clientMarket->children as $key => $client) : ?>
                                <li><a><?php echo $client->title ?></a></li>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>

    </div>

    <hr>

    <div class="client-description hidden-xs"><?php echo $clientDescription->short ?></div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-7 module">
    <div id="client-section-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <?php echo $this->render('_partials/references', ['name' => 'value']) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would liked to update the partial view in the div with class `carousel-inner` when clicking on the anchor tag in div `contact-info`.

I've looked for some examples using ajax but can't find out how to update the partial on click.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want write simple JS/AJAX code with own logic, you can try to use [`Pjax`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-widgets.html#using-gridview-with-pjax).

Something like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="$.pjax.reload('#pjaxId', {timeout : false});">Update Pjax container via AJAX</a>

...

<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

    <?php
    Pjax::begin(['id' => 'pjaxId']);

    echo $this->render('_partials/references', ['name' => 'value']);

    Pjax::end();
    ?>

</div>
```

**UPD:**

If you want to change URL for AJAX updating use:

```
<?php $ajaxUrl = \yii\helpers\Url::to(['some-controller/some-action']); ?>

<a href="#" onclick="$.pjax.reload('#pjaxId', {timeout : false, url: '<?= $ajaxUrl ?>'});">
     Update Pjax container via AJAX
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help IStranger ! But I can't figure out how to update the partials data when the click event is triggered. I'm new to Yii2 and I don't know if what I want to do is based on the right approach. When the click event triggered, it should call an action in the controller and return data that should be passed to the render function in the view without reloading the page.

Comment: Yes, I've tried your code and it works fine but the click event should called an action in SiteController then update the partial with new data but I can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: @Dave747 I updated answer (I hope I correctly understood what you mean "the click event should called an action in SiteController").

Comment: @IStanger - Thank you very much for your help ! To get it to work as I wanted, I had to put this code in my SiteController  `public function actionReferences($id) {
        $items = Item::find()->with(['category'])->where(['category_id' => $id])->status(Item::STATUS_ON)->all();
        return $this->renderPartial('_partials/references', ['ref1' => $items]);
    }` Is it the right way to go as my index view already contain the render function of the partial ? And to prevent the url change when the click event is triggered, I had to put this param `replace: false` in jQuery.pjax.reload.